# How to create a series from 1000 to 9999 using Red language

Tags: red

Using [Red language](https://www.red-lang.org/), I want to choose a random number from 1000 to 9999. Having looked at the docs for [random](http://www.red-by-example.org/#random) I would like for `random` to choose a number from a series ranging from 1000 to 9999.

I know that I can do `999 + (random 9000)` but that does not read well in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

There is a well-established method for computing a random number between two inclusive boundaries:

```
(random(0,1)  * (max - min + 1)) + min
```

Porting it to Red should be straightforward, and wrapping it into a dedicated function would alleviate the "readability" concern. For instance:

```
>> between: func [lower upper][-1 + lower + random upper - lower + 1]
== func [lower upper][-1 + lower + random upper - lower + 1]
>> round average collect [loop 1'000'000 [keep between -10 10]]
== 0.0
```

`-1` above compensates for the fact that `random` range starts from `1`, not `0`.

A poka-yoke `between` would ensure that lower bound is indeed *lower* than upper bound, by picking min/max values out of two given boundaries. I leave this as an excercise for the reader.

Another approach, where you literally pick a random number out of a series, would be:

```
>> thru: make op! func [lower upper][collect [until [keep lower greater? lower: lower + 1 upper]]]
== make op! [[lower upper]]
>> -10 thru 10
== [-10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
>> random/only -10 thru 10
== 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You could define your own function, e.g.

`random2: function [a b] [a - 1 + random b - a + 1]`

then `random2 1000 9999`